# Error on Joomla Website after upgrading from PHP 7.4 to 8.0

Tags: php, joomla

Update 2:

Regarding the error "Call to a member function children() on null", I found these functions.

```
public function hasChildren()
{
    return $this->hasChildNodes();
}

public function children($query = null)
{
    $children = array();

    if (!$this->hasChildren()) {
        return $children;
    }

    if ($query == null) {

        foreach ($this->childNodes as $child) {
            if ($child->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
                $children[] = $child;
            }
        }

        return $children;
    }

    return $this->query(CssSelector::toXPath($query, 'child::'));
}

public function removeChildren()
{
    while ($child = $this->firstChild) {
        $this->removeChild($child);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

#########################################

Update:

I tried to change the code to

```
public function before(...$data): void
    {
      foreach($data as $item) {

        $item = $this->prepareInsert($item);
        $this->parentNode->insertBefore($item, $this);

     }
 }
```

This seems to work, but I get more of those errors. At one point I changed the code from:

```
public function prepend($data)
{
    $data = $this->prepareInsert($data);

    if (isset($data)) {
        if ($this->hasChildren()) {
            $this->insertBefore($data, $this->firstChild);
        } else {
            $this->appendChild($data);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

to this:

```
public function prepend(...$data): void 
{
    foreach($data as $item)
    {
        $item = $this->prepareInsert($item);

        if (isset($item)) {
            if ($this->hasChildren()) {
                $this->insertBefore($item, $this->firstChild);
            } else {
                $this->appendChild($item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I get on my page the error message:

```
Call to a member function children() on null
```

There are no other information.

---

we have installed Joomla 3.10.10 and use the template "Effortless" from BDThemes (which we bought a long time ago via Envato). The template is based on the Warp 7 framework. However, our version is outdated and can no longer be updated, as the template is no longer available on Envato. Currently we are still using PHP 7.4, when we upgrade to PHP 8.0 we get the error message:

"Fatal error: Declaration of Warp\Dom\Element::before($data): void must be compatible with DOMElement::before(...$nodes): void in /homepages/13/d238860405/htdocs/homecms_ta/templates/effortless/warp/src/Warp/Dom/Element.php on line 108"

The code:

```
 public function before($data)
    {
        $data = $this->prepareInsert($data);
        $this->parentNode->insertBefore($data, $this);

        return $this;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix it. I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Looks like there is function like DOMElement::before that returns void, not $this. What happens if you remove `return $this`?

Comment: @qrsngky, no, the return type of both _is_ `void`. If it says that `foo($data): void` must be compatible with `bar(...$nodes): void`, then this is about the part inside the brackets.

Comment: I get still the same error.

Comment: Looks it should be like `before(...$nodes)`, and the body should use `foreach($nodes as $data){...}`

Comment: Parent `before` definition uses variadic as a parameter, which means that you should follow that interface. Yours `before` method allows passing only one parameter. The correct implementation should be something like: ``public function before(...$data): void {foreach ($data as $item) {$this->parentNode->insertBefore($this->prepereInsert($item), $this);} }``

Comment: Okay, the error disappears. But I get now more of this type for other positions. Can you tell me how to change this part:
public function prepend($data)
    {
        $data = $this->prepareInsert($data);

        if (isset($data)) {
            if ($this->hasChildren()) {
                $this->insertBefore($data, $this->firstChild);
            } else {
                $this->appendChild($data);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

Comment: In newer DOM, Element.prepend is also variadic. Again it should be changed to have a signature of `(...$nodes)` and the body like `foreach($nodes as $data){...}`

Comment: @RamonaK. I'm writing in an answer instead of a comment as it's easier to read/format. You should put the additional functions by editing your post (also for the sake of formatting/readability)

Comment: @RamonaK. For the newer error message: you must have a `children(` call somewhere. Can you search the code for that and show it by editing your post? I think it's probably right after `prepend(...)` or `before(...)` so it would complain about the null return value (used to be $this). Instead of `$x = $element -> prepend($A) -> children();`, the new signature would need something like this instead: `$element -> prepend($A) ; $x = $element -> children();`

Comment: @qrsngky I found the function and updated my question. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @RamonaK. The definition of `function children` doesn't show the usage of "member function on null". I think you can search for `->children` or `-> children` elsewhere in the code

Comment: can't find anything for ```->children``` or ```-> children``` .

Comment: Another possibility is something like `$str1 = 'children'; $testObj->{$str1};` or even `$testObj->{"children"}` so maybe you can search for `'children'` or `"children"`.

Comment: Hmm still no result :(

Comment: Maybe try to look for patterns (harder to search since those are split into two parts) like `prepend(...) ->` or `before(...) ->` or `return ...->prepend` or `return ...->before`

Comment: Also no result... ok it's difficult without the complete code :/

Comment: @RamonaK. Yes, and sometimes the problem can be in another file, a file you didn't expect to cause problems

Answer (score 1):

There are some newer methods of Element (not available during the age of IE), for example:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/before
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend
4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

Apparently newer versions of DOMElement PHP tried to follow it too.
All of those are variadic, but the old code of the theme may have assumed that you only had one element to insert.

The easiest way to go around it (minimal change) is probably to use a variadic argument `...$your_variable_name as $data`, then use `foreach($your_variable_name as $data){...}` around your data. And we have to see if there are other side effects (if someone ever uses `$element -> before($oneThing) -> before($anotherThing)`, the second one would fail (as the return type of the first `before` is `void`, unlike the old return of `$this` where you can use `->before` directly after that). 
The `return $this` probably won't get used (I'm not sure about that, though).

For example:

**before**

```
public function before(...$nodes): void
{
    foreach($nodes as $data){
        $data = $this->prepareInsert($data);
        $this->parentNode->insertBefore($data, $this);
    }
   // return $this; 
}
```

**prepend**

```
public function prepend(...$nodes): void 
{ 

    foreach($nodes as $data){
        $data = $this->prepareInsert($data); 
        if (isset($data)) { 
            if ($this->hasChildren()) { 
            $this->insertBefore($data, $this->firstChild); 
            } else { 
                $this->appendChild($data); 
            } 
        }
   }
   // return $this; 
}
```

(note that I can't test it myself as I don't have the complete code of the template you used)